# Python: Find exact sentence from 2 files different files

Tags: python

Good day. I'm new to Python, and looking for code that will search from a text file for exact keywords(could be a long string) on another html file. E.g keyword.txt and data.html. Currently it's only matching the first word instead of exact sentence match.

My keyword file contain:

```
Hello welcome
Hello welcome to this page
Hello world
```

My data file contains:

```
Hello
hello good day
```

for this condition it should return: no match, but currently it's returning "match found".

And how to ensure it searches for all the keywords line by line against the html page.

Really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

my current code:

```
import re

keyfile = 'keyword.txt'
testfile = 'data.txt'
keys = set(key.lower() for key in
    re.findall(r'\w+', open(keyfile , "r").readline()))
with open(testfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        words = set(word.lower() for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line))
        if keys & words:
            print "match found"
```

Comment: @Kalaireas Please check the code indentation if it's correct.

Comment: `if keys & words:` finds the intersection of `keys` and `words` and check if it is nonempty.  Are you looking to match the contents of the entire lines of your keyfile?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, yes, i want to find exact match of contents (line by line) of the keyfile against the data file. e.g if any of the line matches against the data.html file then it should print "match" else no.

Comment: @MYGz, corrected.

Comment: `readline` should be `readlines`. You can omit this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Modify line 6. from `re.findall(r'\w+', open(keyfile , "r").readline()))` to be `open(keyfile , "r"))` to put entire lines into `key` set, not just the words. You also need to modify the matching part to match the lines.

So your code will look like this:

```
import re

keyfile = 'keyword.txt'
testfile = 'data.txt'
keys = set(key.lower() for key in
    open(keyfile , "r"))
with open(testfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.lower() in keys:
            print "match found"
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: not really looks like not it's not even capturing the same word.

Comment: The `keys` definition leaks an unclosed file handle.